# Why is RadioGroup.check() and RadioButton.setChecked() failing?

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I have a RadioGroup with 2 RadioButtons. When clicked, some condition is validated, and, based on the outcome, the click should happen, otherwise revert.

However, it seems I can't set the check programmatically.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onCheckedChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    switch (buttonView.getId()){
        case R.id.radio_adresse:
            if(radioAdresse.isChecked()){
                getEditTextPlz().setEnabled(true);
                getEditTextOrt().setEnabled(true);
                getEditTextStrasse().setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                getEditTextPlz().setEnabled(false);
                getEditTextOrt().setEnabled(false);
                getEditTextStrasse().setEnabled(false);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.radio_aktueller_standort:
            if(isLocationAvailable()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Location available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(radioAktuellerStandort.isChecked()){
                    getEditTextPlz().setEnabled(false);
                    getEditTextOrt().setEnabled(false);
                    getEditTextStrasse().setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    getEditTextPlz().setEnabled(true);
                    getEditTextOrt().setEnabled(true);
                    getEditTextStrasse().setEnabled(true);
                }
            } else {
                if(isChecked){

                } else {

                }
                Toast.makeText(this, "Location NOT available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                searchModeRadioGroup.clearCheck();
                searchModeRadioGroup.check(R.id.radio_adresse);
                radioAdresse.setSelected(true);
                radioAktuellerStandort.setSelected(false);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is the XML:

```
        <RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/search_mode_radio_group"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_span="2">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_adresse"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/adresse"
                android:checked="true"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_aktueller_standort"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/aktueller_standort"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

As you can see at the end of my event handler, I tried several methods, but none works...
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I used the onClick event instead of onCheckedChanged event, and it worked.